# MS Access subquery from identical table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am currently working on an access database where we collect customers feedback.

I have one table with the following structure and data :

[image: table data and structure]

And I want to display the following result :

[image: result]

Indeed, what I want is a MS Access Request that displays, for every date value in my table, the amount of records that matches the same date on the column "date_import" (2nd column of the result) and the amount of records that matches this criteria on the column "date_answered" (3rd column of the result).

I have no idea how to do this since all the subqueries should be aware of each other.

Has anyone ever faced this issue and might be able to help me ?

Thanks in advance,

P.S. : I'm using the 2016 version of MS Access but I'm pretty sure what I'm trying to do is also achievable in previous versions of Access, this is what I added several tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think this will work:

```
select dte, sum(is_contact), sum(is_answer)
from (select date_import as dte, 1 as is_contact, 0 as is_answer
      from t
      union all
      select date_answers, 0 as is_contact, 1 as is_answer
      from t
     ) t
group by dte;
```

Not all versions of MS Access allow `union all` in the `FROM` clause.  If that is a problem, you can create a view and then select from the view.

Comment: Oh wow ! This seems to work like a charm ! You've just solved hours of brain overheat with so few lines. Thanks a lot man !

Well, in my case I also had to make one more modification to my access database :
my dates were stored with the time (21/10/2020 12:00:00 - french format) and i would get several lines per day depending on the actual time of each date value. What I did was simple : I just added two columns and populated them with the following SQL :
UPDATE [Table] SET [New date column] = CDate(Format([date time column], "dd/mm/yyyy")) WHERE [date time column] IS NOT NULL;